# SOLR or Query does not combine filters

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr4, solarium

Ive 5 Entries like following

- spitze 1
- spitze 2
- spitze 3
- spritze 1
- spritze 2

Results are like following

`&q=spitze~&defType=edismax`

- spitze 1
- spitze 2
- spitze 3
- spritze 1
- spritze 2

`&q=*spitze*&defType=edismax`

- spitze 1
- spitze 2
- spitze 3

`&q=(spitze~)-(*spitze*)&defType=edismax`

- spritze 1
- spritze 2

`&q=(spitze~)||(*spitze*)&defType=edismax`

- spitze 1
- spitze 2
- spitze 3

so why does this or statement not work. it thought it would combine both and give me all 5 results. Where is my error in this query...

Comment: Have you tried using `OR` instead? (capital letters, spaces around it? or set `q.op=OR` to make Solr use or by default between terms?

Comment: @MatsLindh i tried both || and OR as well as settings the q.op to OR or ||

Comment: You can append `&debug=all` to the query string to get the generated query - you might be able to see what edismax is doing with what you've entered (since edismax isn't using Lucene syntax directly).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your hint. The parsed query started with a + so i had to add an * in front of the query to include everything at first